# Unknown property 'actionSupportController.wpetwizardcontroller.Good_with_Cats__c' error?

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

I am getting above error.

```
    public class actionSupportController {
    public List<PCS_Household__c> lstQuery{get;set;} 
    public List<PCS_Household__c> OnlstQuery{get;set;}
    public string ID_c{get;set;}      
    public string test{get;set;}

    public List<wpetwizardcontroller> chrcs{get;set;}
    public List<Characteristics__c> selctchr{get;set;}
    public List<Pets_Information__c> selctpet{get;set;}

    public List<wpetwizardcontroller> getchrc(){
     if(chrcs==null){
       chrcs=new List<wpetwizardcontroller>();
        for(Characteristics__c chrc:[SELECT ID,Good_with_Cats__c,Pet_ID__r.Gender__c,Pet_ID__r.Height__c,Pet_ID__r.Name__c,Pet_ID__r.pet__c,Pet_ID__r.Pet_Photo__c,Pet_ID__r.Status__c FROM Characteristics__c where Good_with_Cats__c=:true]){
          chrcs.add(new wpetwizardcontroller(chrc));
      }
    }
        return chrcs;
    }

    public PageReference incrementCounter() {
       string Query='';
        Query='SELECT ID,Name,Household__c,Phone__c,of_Childrens__c,of_Exiting_Pets__c,Address__c,Previous_Dog__c FROM PCS_Household__c where ID=:test';        
        system.debug('==Query=='+Query);
        OnlstQuery=Database.query(Query);
        system.debug('==lstQuery=='+OnlstQuery);
        return null;
    }

     public Void doSearch(){
        string Query='';
        Query='SELECT ID,Name,Household__c,Phone__c,of_Childrens__c,of_Exiting_Pets__c,Address__c,Previous_Dog__c FROM PCS_Household__c where Household__c LIKE \'%'+ID_c+'%\'';
        system.debug('==Query=='+Query);
        lstQuery=Database.query(Query);
        system.debug('==lstQuery=='+lstQuery);
    }

    public void nullify(){
        lstQuery.clear();
    }

    public PageReference nextpage() {

        upsert OnlstQuery;

        return Page.cc;
    }

      public class wpetwizardcontroller{
        public Characteristics__c chrc{get;set;} 
        public boolean selectd{get;set;}

        public wpetwizardcontroller(Characteristics__c chrc){
            this.chrc=chrc;
            selectd=false;

        }

    }

}


    <apex:page Controller="actionSupportController">
   <apex:form >
       <apex:pageBlock >
            Household Name: <apex:inputText value="{!ID_c}"/>
           </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Characteristics Information">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!chrc}" var="eachchr">
        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!eachchr.Good_with_Cats__c}"/>Goods with Cats<br/>       
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!eachchr.HighNeed__c}"/>High Need<br/>
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!eachchr.Non_shedder__c}"/>Non-shedder<br/>
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!eachchr.Predatory_Tendencies__c}"/>Predatory Tendencies<br/>
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!eachchr.kid_friendly__c}"/>Kid Friendly<br/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>


       <br/><apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!getchrc}" rerender="sblck"/>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:outputPanel id="sblck">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Search Results">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!selctpet}" var="eachpet">
        <apex:column value="{!eachpet.Name}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!eachpet.Gender__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!eachpet.Height__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!eachpet.Name__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!eachpet.pet__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!eachpet.Pet_Photo__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!eachpet.Status__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:outputPanel>
       <apex:commandButton value="Request Adoption"/>
   </apex:form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Update your PBT into this

```
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!chrc}" var="eachchr">
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!eachchr.chrc.Good_with_Cats__c}"/>Goods with Cats<br/>       
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!eachchr.chrc.HighNeed__c}"/>High Need<br/>
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!eachchr.chrc.Non_shedder__c}"/>Non-shedder<br/>
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!eachchr.chrc.Predatory_Tendencies__c}"/>Predatory Tendencies<br/>
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!eachchr.chrc.kid_friendly__c}"/>Kid Friendly<br/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

This will solve your problem.

Also give a read to [Wrapper Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Wrapper_Class) so help better understand how we will refer the wrapper class variable.

**UPDATE**

Here is how you will display it correctly

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!chrc}" var="eachchr">
     <apex:column headervalue="Heading here>
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!eachchr.chrc.Good_with_Cats__c}"/>Goods with Cats
    </apex:column> 
    //use same format for all checkboxes.
```

Comment: but i want to display the checkbox. if i called the checkbox in pageblocktable means it is not displaying

Comment: then you need to update your PBT code

Comment: please give some example

Comment: @muralimano check my updated code.

Comment: i used tushar but i am getting an error   <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!chrc}" var="eachchr">
               <apex:column headervalue="heading">
               <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!eachchr.chrc.Good_with_Cats__c}"/>Goods with Cats
               </apex:column>
               <apex:column headervalue="heading">
               <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!eachchr.chrc.Good_with_Cats__c}"/>Goods with Cats
               </apex:column>
               
           </apex:pageBlockTable>

Comment: what error you are getting @muralimano

Answer (score 0):

List name in the pageblocktable (value attribute) and accessing wrapper list variables in the page is wrong.

Try this code.

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!chrcs}" var="eachchr">
    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!eachchr.chrc.Good_with_Cats__c}"/>Goods with Cats<br/>       
    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!eachchr.chrc.HighNeed__c}"/>High Need<br/>
    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!eachchr.chrc.Non_shedder__c}"/>Non-shedder<br/>
    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!eachchr.chrc.Predatory_Tendencies__c}"/>Predatory Tendencies<br/>
    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!eachchr.chrc.kid_friendly__c}"/>Kid Friendly<br/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```